# How to reactively filter which columns of a datatable are displayed?

Tags: r, if-statement, reactive-programming

I am trying to build an interactive data table that changes the displayed columns based on filters chosen by the user. The aim is to have a user select the columns they want to see via a dropdown, which will then cause the datatable to display those columns only.

```
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <-
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 4,
          pickerInput(inputId = "index_picker",
                      label = "Select index/indices", 
                      choices = c("RPI", "RPIX", "CPI", "GDP Deflator"),
                      selected = "RPI",
                      multiple = T
                      )      
          )
      )
    
        fluidRow(   
          box(DT::dataTableOutput("index_table"), title = "Historic Inflation Indices", width = 12,
solidHeader = T, status = "primary")
          )
        )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
df_filt <- reactive({
  
  if({
    input$index_picker == "RPI" &
      !is.null()
  })
    df_index %>%
    select(Period, RPI.YOY, RPI.INDEX)
  
  else if({
    input$index_picker == "RPIX"
    })
    df_index %>%
    select(Period, RPIX.YOY, RPIX.INDEX)
  })
  
  output$index_table <- renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(df_filt(),
                  options = 
                    list(dom = "itB",
                         fixedHeader = T
                         ),
                  rownames = F
                  )
    })
}
```

I have similar code to the above that filters based on the row instead, and this works just fine, however, for this column filtering I  am getting this error:

`Warning in if ({ : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

I understand that I'm passing a vector to the if statement, but not sure how to recode - would anyone be able to help?

Comment: The problem is in you if clause `input$index_picker`  can be of length larger than one, in which case this if statement `input$index_picker == "RPI"` throws the warning your encountered. You have to think about the exact condition you want to test in the if clause. Do you mean if `any` of the selected rows contains `"RPI"`? What should happen if neither `"RPI"` nor `"RPIX"` is selected?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I want to have it so that the user can select up to all 4 options from `index_picker` , and if none are selected then for the selection (and) table to default to just `"RPI"`